# BST : Increment each key value by sum of all other greater keys

Tags: java

Problem statement : Given a Binary Search Tree (BST), convert it to a Binary Tree such that every key of the original BST is changed to key plus sum of all greater keys in BST.

```
Input:  BST
              5
            /   \
           2     13
                /  \
               11  14

Output: The given BST is converted to following Binary Tree

              43
             /  \
            45   27
                /  \
               38   14
```

I was able to dig out this piece of code online which works, but I couldn't really grasp it. Passing a variable to maintain the previous sum so far further complicates my understanding.

Please care to explain to explain with a better code. Or make the below code more intuitive.

```
public class BSTWithInts
{
    private Node root;

    private class Node
    {
        Node leftChild;
        Integer item;
        Node rightChild;
    }

    public void addsNodes()
    {
        addSumUtil(root, 0);
    }


    private int addSumUtil(Node node, int sum)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return 0;

        if ( node.rightChild != null )
        {
            sum = addSumUtil(node.rightChild, sum);
        }
        if ( node.leftChild != null )   
        {
            sum = addSumUtil(node.leftChild, sum);

            // why are we doing this here, shouldn't we just 
            // traverse right tree only first
        }

       node.item += sum;
       sum = node.item;
       return sum;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just realised the code is not working the way it should.

```
              5             
            /   \
           2     13

    should give 

             18
            /   \
          20     13

    and not      
             20
            /   \
          15    13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the simplest way you'd do this, remembering that it's a search tree, so everything's in order.  You'd want to start with the highest number.  Record it and leave it alone.  Then the 2nd-highest number: add the highest number to it, and keep a copy, because that's also "the sum of all numbers higher than the 3rd highest number".  Add that to the 3rd highest number and keep the sum because that will be added to the 4th highest.  You drag that sum around, each time increasing it by the current number (and vice versa).  When you get to the smallest number, you've got the sum of the rest ofthe tree there, ready to add to it.

Also, I think the code you found is wrong, even if it does work on the sample tree.  It should look more like:

```
private int addSumUtil(Node node, int sum)
{
    if (node == null) {
        return sum;
    }

    sum = addSumUtil(node.rightChild, sum);
    sum = node.item += sum;
    sum = addSumUtil(node.leftChild, sum);

    return sum;
}
```

Note that `sum = addSumUtil(null, sum);` is a noop.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that the code I found was wrong. Thanks, this is very helpful. But one more question : Can we doing it iteratively ? Passing state variables in function stack confuses me.

Comment: Because it's a tree, it will be even more confusing if it's iterative.  If it helps, add this line before the `+=` assignment: `System.err.format("%d + %d = %n", node.item, sum, node.item + sum);`  This will show you what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's going on in the above code you need to understand how the recursion works.

The simple way start understanding this would be to use a System.out.println statement within the processing for the left and right children to understand better what is happening:

```
        if ( node.rightChild != null )
        {
            System.out.println("Accessing right child: "+node.rightChild.item);
            sum = addSumUtil(node.rightChild, sum);
        }
        if ( node.leftChild != null )   
        {
            System.out.println("Accessing left child: "+node.leftChild.item);
            sum = addSumUtil(node.leftChild, sum);

            // why are we doing this here, shouldn't we just 
            // traverse right tree only first
        }
```

You will find the output of the print statements to be in the following order thus confirming that the right child of every node is evaluated before its left child.

```
Accessing right child: 13
Accessing right child: 14
Accessing left child: 11
Accessing left child: 2
```

Comment: Well, after putting the print statements I realise that this ode is wrong. It is incrementing the left child of a node first and then the node. Instead it should increment the node first, and then the left child. See edits.